# Blob: Unable to decode image at URL

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, office-js, uint8array

I'm currently making a Word Web Add-in.
This uses Internet Explorer as engine.
My Add-in needs to load multiple selected images from the users computer.

Because some of the selected images might be quite big, I resize them using HTML5 canvas. This is my code to resize:

```
    function makeSmallImage(imageContainer, retries)
    {
        if (retries === undefined)
            retries = 0;

        console.log('Resizing image..')
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
        {
            img = img || new Image();

            img.onload = function ()
            {
                // calculate new size
                var width = 200;
                var height = Math.floor((width / img.naturalWidth) * img.naturalHeight);

                console.log('new size', width, height);

                try
                {
                    // create an off-screen canvas
                    canvas = canvas || document.createElement('canvas'),
                        ctx = ctx || canvas.getContext('2d');

                    // antialiasing
                    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;

                    // set its dimension to target size
                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;

                    // draw source image into the off-screen canvas:
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                    // clean up
                    imageContainer.largeData = undefined;
                    if (img.src.substr(0, 4) === 'blob')
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
                    img.src = '';

                    // encode image to data-uri with base64 version of compressed image
                    var newDataUri = canvas.toDataURL();
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    console.log('Image resized!');
                    imageContainer.resizedData = newDataUri;

                    resolve(imageContainer);
                }
                catch (e)
                {
                    if (img.src !== undefined && img.src.substr(0, 4) === 'blob')
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);

                    console.log(e);
                    if (e.message === "Unspecified error." && retries < 5)
                    {
                        setTimeout(function (imgContainer, re)
                        {
                            makeSmallImage(imgContainer, re).then(resolve).catch(reject);
                        }, 2000, imageContainer, retries + 1);
                    }
                    else
                        reject('There was an error while trying to resize one of the images!');
                }
            };

            try
            {
                var blob = new Blob([imageContainer.largeData]);
                img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            } catch (e)
            {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
}
```

'img', 'canvas' and 'ctx' are global variables, so the same elements are reused.
'imgcontainer.largedata' is an uint8array. To avoid a lot of memory usage i'm loading and resizing the images one by one.

Despite of that, after loading for example 120 images of 10mb, it might happen that I get an error:

> Unable to decode image at URL:
>   'blob:D5EFA3E0-EDE2-47E8-A91E-EAEAD97324F6'

I then get an exception "Unspecified error", with not a lot more info.
You can see in the code now that I added a litle mechanism to try again, but all new attempts fail.

I think the reason is that internet explorer is using too much memory. I think some resources are not being cleaned up correctly, but I can't seem to spot a memory leak in my code here (if you can, please let me know).

Does anybody have an idea of how I could fix this, or work around this?

Comment: Some images have been renamed with the wrong extension. eg. jpg images renamed with a gif extension. Identify which images raise the "Unable to decode image at URL" and open them with an image editor like Irfranview, which can detect when the file extension does not match the mime-type bytes and offer to convert the image file back to its 'natural' extension/mime-type.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RobParsons, but I don't think that's the case. It also happens with pictures that come right from a camera.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to resize the image, why not directly use the office APIs? you can first get the images, then use the height/width property to resize it, such as

```
image1.height = 5; image1.width = 5;
```

Comment: This is not possible, because then I have to keep all the images in memory at their original size.